# GPU problem - Boot Hangs on Grey Screen

Tags: startup, hardware, graphics, gpu

I found this according to my problem in this thread:
[Boot hangs on grey screen (even when booting from USB drive with fresh OS X install)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120507/boot-hangs-on-grey-screen-even-when-booting-from-usb-drive-with-fresh-os-x-inst?answertab=active#tab-top)

My MacBook Pro 15" Early 2011 with AMD Radeon HD 6750M exhibited display corruption and associated system crashes/resets over a period of two weeks before it entirely failed to boot. The boot would progress through the grey screen with the Apple logo and spinner, but just when it seems it should have switched to the login screen the Apple logo and spinner would disappear and hang on a blank grey screen.

Initially I suspected hard-drive corruption and went about trying to remedy that. Unsuccessfully, I tried the following, with each continuing to hang as described above:

Safe boot
Boot into recovery (including Internet Recovery)
Boot from install media on USB drive
Boot from OS X installation on USB drive
Clear NVRAM
Reset SMC

I also ran the Apple Hardware Test many times without it finding any issues.

Verbose safe boot (Cmd+Shift+V) output everything that I'd expect to see but would then hang as described above.

After coming across more posts online at Apple's discussion forums of GPU related problems I revisited this as the cause:

[2011 MacBook Pro and Discrete Graphics Card](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22751155#22751155) or
[2011 MacBook Pro and Discrete Graphics Card](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4766577?start=210&tstart=0)

Attempting to boot Ubuntu from a USB flash drive, I could only get as far as GRUB. When trying to boot Ubuntu Desktop or run the graphicstest in GRUB the system would hang.

At this point, running Apple Hardware Test hung right before the end of the standard test, possibly [guessing] when doing a video test.

Based on the advice in the Apple Discussions posts above I did the following:

Boot into Single-User mode
Execute the following commands:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy /
/sbin/mount -uw /
mkdir /Disabled_System_Library_Extensions
cd /Disabled_System_Library_Extensions
mv /System/Library/Extensions/ATI* .
mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMD* .
touch /System/Library/Extensions
exit
```

This time the machine booted all the way through. However, graphics are extremely slow, even just transitions when minimizing windows. I will be taking my MBP to Apple to demand a replacement as the large number of reports of others facing similar issues makes it look like a recurrence of a similar GPU-related failure that resulted in them doing a recall.

**But when I use the "mv" command the files won't get moved (neither deleted) and it shows me:

Sandbox deny(01) file-write-unlinked…**

**Any Solution ?**

Comment: See: [MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program for Video Issues](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/).

Comment: @klanomath Yep, that's the issue. Happened to my old MBP too (just a greenish rather than grey screen).

Answer (score 111):

## Background and explanations

Please read all of this post at least once from start to finish before taking any action.

**All** MacBook Pros from 2011 have a **serious design defect**. The thermal management and the generated heat together with the robustness of the discrete AMD graphics chips do not match up very well. Apple knew this and acted like a typical [Soapy Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soapy_Smith), only reacting to this after an outrage. This scandal is known as RadeonGate. [Only threatened with class-action law suit Apple finally offered a so called "Repair Extension Program"](http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/01/15/2011-macbook-pro-graphics-class-action-suit-expands-accuses-apple-of-concealing-defects).

[The Repair Extension program is not available anymore](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/). The only *real* way to fix this problem is to replace the AMD chip alone. Not the logic board. Not "re-balling", not "reflowing", not "baking". Apple replaced a failed chip with a failing chip. Time and time again. Only replacing the graphics chip is still a costly hardware procedure for such a vintage laptop.

The only known way – that is: with software alone – to get a 2011 MacBook Pro (8,2) with 'only' a failed AMD graphics chip to almost reliably turn on again and boot into macOS and be quite useable *with an accelerated* GUI is this guide or a variation of it. Most previous tips just removed all AMD-kexts and this results in a horrible user experience with no GUI acceleration at all.

It is necessary to know your exact OS version. The following guide will be simpler for Yosemite but assumes El Capitan or newer. El Capitan, Sierra and High Sierra need SIP (System Integrity Protection) disabled. On previous systems (10.6–10.10) these steps are unnecessary.

**Important:** This guide assumes further that all kexts are still in their default location /System/Library/Extensions. Having all AMD-kexts there *except one* is beneficial for 'proper' operation. Previous hacks in this direction might have instructed you to move, or worse: *remove* all AMD*/ATI* kernel extensions. If that is the case: either move the kexts back into their default location or reinstall a system of your choice. Having most of the AMD kexts in place *and* then having the X3000-kext loaded with a delay will enable power management of the GPU which will otherwise burn electricity for nothing (and might hasten the final heat death of the chip on top of that). To reiterate: Only the file `AMDRadeonX3000.kext` really has be *absent* on boot to enable a successful startup, but all other (needed) AMD drivers should be in their default location and the X3000-kext loaded afterwards/delayed to get back into a realm of almost sensible power and temperature management.

## Bypassing the discrete graphics chip

To get some display acceleration back it will be necessary to force the machine to not boot in discrete graphics (dGPU) but directly into integrated graphics (iGPU) and stay in this mode.

Booting into dGPU mode is the default on Macs with two switchable graphics cards. The procedure below will set an NVRAM variable that disables the dGPU and forces the system to only use the integrated Intel graphics even when booting.

The NVRAM variable is undocumented but appears to be universally applicable to all Macs with two switchable graphics cards. That means it should work on iMacs and MacBook Pros. Whether they have AMD or NVIDIA chips. The specifics about the drivers that might be necessary to move only cover AMD in this guide. **But the NVRAM variable will bypass the discrete graphics chip in any case.**

This will give you back your machine – but you will lose some features: e.g. the ability to drive an external display from the DisplayPort, a bit of 3D performance. Thunderbolt data connections should work.

In case this guide fails or is not wanted anymore: this procedure is pure software configuration and therefore fully reversible at any time with simple [NVRAM reset](https://support.apple.com/HT204063).

## The initial procedure:

### Part 1: Disable SIP, disable dGPU, move one kernel extension

1. To start from a clean slate: reset SMC and NVRAM:
   shutdown, unplug everything except power, now hold

   <kbd>leftShift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> 
   and release all at the same time;
2. Now power on again and hold

   <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
   at the same time until you hear the startup chime two times.
3. Boot into Single User Recovery by holding

   <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
4. Disable SIP: enter:

   `csrutil disable`
5. disable dGPU on boot with setting the following variable:

   `nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00`
6. enable verbose boot mode:

   `nvram boot-args="-v"`
7. reboot into Single User-mode by holding

   <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>  on boot
8. mount root partition writeable

   `/sbin/mount -uw /`
9. make a kext-backup directory

   `mkdir -p /System/Library/Extensions-off`
10. only move ONE offending kext out of the way:

    `mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX3000.kext  /System/Library/Extensions-off/`
11. inform the system to update its kextcache:

    `touch /System/Library/Extensions/`
12. reboot normally:

You should now have an iGPU-accelerated display, but the system doesn't know how to power-management the failed AMD-chip. (In this state the GPU is always idling with relatively high power, consuming quite a bit of battery when unplugged and leading to GPU temperatures from 60°C upwards [on average 60-85°C], despite not being otherwise unused.)

### Part 2: improve thermal and power management

For improved power management of the disabled GPU you have to either manually load the one crucial kext *after* boot by:

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions-off/AMDRadeonX3000.kext
```

If you have a temperature sensor application you might want to have it open before issuing the above command and watch the temps drop…

Automate this with the following LoginHook that will get executed after the next reboot:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/LoginHook
sudo nano /Library/LoginHook/LoadX3000.sh
```

with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
kextload  /System/Library/Extensions-off/AMDRadeonX3000.kext
pmset -a force gpuswitch 0    # undocumented/experimental
exit 0
```

then make it<sup>*1</sup> executable and active:

```
sudo chmod a+x /Library/LoginHook/LoadX3000.sh  
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /Library/LoginHook/LoadX3000.sh
```

*1: The undocumented use of this pmset command seems to improve sleep/wake/shutdown behaviour. If it doesn't, experiment with leaving it out.
See Disclaimer below. The following is just speculation: sleep/wake/shutdown may remain troublesome. The theory here is that "something slowly corrupts" what is saved in the SMC. Therefore, resetting the SMC and re-applying the variable hack seems to alleviate the situation for a time.  (Permanent solutions for this welcome!) As short time workarounds you might want to try to avoid "lid-closing sleep", that seems to give more trouble than other methods (Apple-Menu, Keyboard-Shorcut). Apparent hangs on shutdown are usually just very long delays that will shutdown, eventually, cleanly and successfully.
Unscientific sampling suggests that Yosemite is worst for this and El Capitan and Sierra much better behaved in this regard.

Manually or otherwise delayed loading of this crucial kernel extension allows the system to handle power management a bit better. The battery will be less used and the temperatures emanating from the unused GPU will drop to a range significantly below 50°C (on average between 15-50°C).

For proper power management the minimal set of loaded kexts are on boot (versions for 10.12.6, check with `kextstat | grep AMD`):

```
com.apple.kext.AMDLegacySupport (1.5.1) 
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller (1.5.1)  
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport (1.5.1)
com.apple.kext.AMDLegacyFramebuffer (1.5.1)
```

And if the above method of loading succeeded this should appear added to the list:

```
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000 (1.5.1)
```

**A final step is to reboot once again into SingleUserRecovery**
Do this with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
after the commandline becomes active, enter:

```
 nvram boot-args="-v agc=0"
```

and reboot normally.

This will cool down the dGPU a bit further.

It is imperative to issue this command from SingleUserRecovery since the system with SIP enabled [will block](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315120/setting-a-nvram-variable-in-normal-boot-not-permitted-but-allowed-in-recovery-mo) your attempts to set this variable when booted from the normal boot volume, whether in normal full boot mode or regular SingleUser.
It is important to note that therefor this step cannot be easily integrated into the force-iGPU.sh script (that you will be creating in a minute) and has to be repeated on its own after a NVRAM reset.

This last step assumes that SystemIntegretyProtection has been reenabled. But if SIP is intentionally and permanently kept off, then this step *can* be integrated in the force-iGPU.sh script above.
But since somehow I intended to keep SIP off permanently and it was turned back on without me noticing it, reliance on SIP staying "off" might be not the best approach. Clearing NVRAM, where SIP settings are stored, might be one such unforeseen disturbance.

### Preventive measures for future use

There are two further caveats to know:
This is reversible when the SMC/NVRAM is reset. If that happens the GPU-power-pref NVRAM-variable can or even has to be set again to force the use of the iGPU from boot-time.

Since this can happen quite easily (and is often erroneously recommended way too many times than it is actually useful), you should probably prepare for such a scenario and create a simple script to greatly speed up the process and also make entering the necessary variable much less error prone:

```
 sudo nano /force-iGPU-boot.sh
```

– Enter the following content to this file:

```
#/bin/sh
sudo nvram boot-args="-v"
sudo nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00
exit 0
```

– Now make that executable:

```
sudo chmod a+x /force-iGPU-boot.sh
```

In the future, when the SMC/PRAM/NVRAM gets reset to default values it is now possible to boot into SingleUser with:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

– And after mounting your boot-volume read-write to execute just this single line:

```
sh /force-iGPU-boot.sh
```

Remember that the agc variable is now also cleared. (See above)
Also, make sure you set the default boot-volume again in System Preferences > Startup Disk.

## Part 3: Handling Updates from Apple

This setup has now one kext in a place Apple's installers do not expect. That is why in this guide SIP has not been reenabled. If an update that contains changes to the AMD drivers is about to take place it is advisable to move back the AMDRadeonX3000.kext to its default location *before* the update process. Otherwise the updater writes at least another kext of a different version to its default location or at worst you end up with an undefined state of partially non-matching drivers.

After any system update the folder /System/Library/Extensions has to be checked for the offending kext. Its presence there will lead to e.g. a boot hang on Yosemite and Sierra, an overheating boot-loop in High Sierra.

**Upgrading to High Sierra 10.13:** with this hack in place is *almost* straightforward: Despite applying a  firmware update  the installation process should not touch the NVRAM variable. The installation process also does not use a fully accelerated AMD chip but basic acceleration that is not problematic regarding this hack. However, as noted in the paragraph above the first boot into a system that is finished installing but just about to start the setup process will produce a heat/crash induced boot loop. The offending kernel extension has to be moved again like described above. (Starting at Step 3) After moving the kext, all shall be well.

### Important notice for recent updates from Apple:

**The last updates for (High) Sierra *break* the machine again.** It updates the firmware, RecoveryPartition, seems to disable the possibility to boot into SingleUserRecoveryMode
and to top it off it installs – even with the DeltaUpdate – a working AMDRadeonX3000.kext!
Without preparation and with just the machine at hand you will be stuck a bit.

In case SingleUserRecoveryMode is gone for good, use regular RecoveryMode. Results are the same, it is just a little slower to boot into: the above procedure is still valid, and faster for all previous versions of Mac OS X/macOS.

If you update to 10.13.6, or later:
Replace the instructions for SingleUserRecoveryMode (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) with regular RecoveryMode (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) and disable SIP via Terminal ([Example for this precise use case](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336676/251859)).

In case you find that even regular RecoveryMode doesn't work as expected:
Workarounds for the inability to disable SIP with SingleUserRecovery:

1. First, boot into single user recovery mode. csrutil edits are not allowed in this mode, but can set the gpu-power-prefs nvram property. This will help to reboot  the machine in recovery mode. Then you have to replace the instructions for SingleUserRecoveryMode (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) with regular RecoveryMode (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) and disable SIP via Terminal ([Example for thi use case](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336676/251859)).
2. Before an update, prepare a bootable volume. That can be an external disk or a stick. Any version that boots the machine will be fine. Such a drive can be created on another Mac.
   Keep in mind that on the external drive the AMDRadeonX3000.kext has to be (re)moved as well. Try booting from that drive. Only if that works as expected and you can mount your internal drive with it: reboot from your internal drive and proceed with the update of your internal drive/system to 10.13.6.
   After the update is nearly finished, one reboot will hang. Force a shutdown and reboot from your external drive. Mount the internal drive and move the Radeon.kext. SIP only protects the booted system.
3. Suggested somewhere online, but really a desperate guess and untested: Instead of SingleUserRecoveryMode with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> you might try InternetRecoverySingleUserMode <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>.
   Alternatively, it might be worth a try to see whether SafeRecoveryMode works <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>.

> Graphical recovery mode might not work too, as it did for me. However, in the last version of High Sierra, it is still possible to boot to single user recovery mode. It just needs good timing. The trick is to first enable recovery mode by pressing cmd+R and immediately after it is recognized the cmd+S command for the single user mode. The exact moment has to be figured out by the user. If cmd+R+S are pressed at the same time, only single user mode will be activated. If first cmd+R is pressed and cmd+S is pressed too late, graphical recovery mode is loaded. – TAKeanice ↵

### Screen brightness keys not working in High Sierra or Mojave?

Apple changed how keyboard events for changing screen brightness are handled in High Sierra. With this hack in place the keys *might* be functionless. If that's the case: One more reason to stay with Sierra.

But you might also resort to another software solution. Ready made applications or apps or extensions:

- E.g.: [Brightness Slider on the AppStore](https://itunes.apple.com/app/brightness-slider/id456624497?mt=12) offers customizable keyboard shortcuts.
- https://github.com/stecker870/MacBook-Pro-15-Zoll-late-2011-Graphics-Card-Fix- (patched AppleGraphicsControl.kext for 10.13 *and* 10.14! The latter requires of course more patching to even install…, see below)

## Recommended OS version

This hack was developed with machines running Yosemite (10.10) to Sierra (10.12). Working nicely on those.

### High Sierra

High Sierra (10.13) works nice as well. And it is the last version 'officially fully supported by Apple'. Well, formerly supported. It works fine with this hack, *and* you might re-enable SIP. To get more security updates you have to go one step further:

### Mojave

With Mojave (10.14) the install process is totally unspported by Apple and gets much more complicated:

1. You need to install High Sierra once, to get the firmware updates for APFS boot support from Apple. (Alternative: [part of the dosdude1 patch guide](http://dosdude1.com/mojave/).)
2. You need to follow the procedures required by the [dosdude1 patcher.](http://dosdude1.com/mojave/)
3. This means trusting 'that guy'.
4. Lots of reboots required.
5. NVRAM setting gets seemingly always lost in the process — re-apply like described above once the patch/install procedure is finished. (If you get weird colours eg in Safari's tabs after upgrade to 10.14: AMD is active…, check via System Report)
6. Caveat: do *not* follow dosdude1's GPU-disabling recommendation! — ; Use the one above, as usual (The dosdude1 version runs hotter…). Because, once you accept this Franken-status of 'support' from Apple, this patched OS, SIP *now* kept off by necessity (!), plus the usual downsides from this hack (and eg newer Safari versions killing your favourite extensions…)
7. *You will need to keep around an external volume*/USB-Stick with the patched installer, otherwise your machine may become unbootable by updates from Apple…
8. Mojave is currently the best working OS (IMO) for this machine. Try it out.

---

To avoid crashes/hangs/boot-loops – which are never a good idea for your filesystem – on a fresh install or an upgrade: make sure to babysit the installation process and always boot into SafeMode (keep <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed during boot-ups until the kext is moved into a safe place –– the installation should proceed just fine in SafeMode.

## **Closing Remarks and Recommendations**

Further: this laptop is overheating, no matter what you do. The cooling system is inadequate and the huge number of failing AMD chips are just proof of that.

To prolong the life of this now hacked machine it is advisable to abstain from really heavy lifting over prolonged stretches of time.
Strictly follow the usual recommendations for laptops: use on hard surfaces, keep the fans and fins inside it clean. Using any fancontrol software with relatively aggressive settings should also help: like [smcFanControl](https://www.eidac.de/smcfancontrol/smcfancontrol_2_6.zip), MacsFanControl, or TGPro (both commercial).

**Disclaimer:** This whole procedure is no magic bullet. The state of failure for these chips not 100% predictable. Very few users have issues even with this hack in place: there might be issues with rebooting, going to sleep or waking up properly, most of them coming from users with Yosemite, the least trouble seems to be on Sierra. In these cases it seems sometimes necessary to *not use* the AMDRadeonX3000.kext, and therefore also not the LoginHook from Part 3. (But see the additional note under *1 above.) High Sierra users report issues with their displays backlight adjustment.

In some cases, even with all these measures in place it seems that the still functioning Thunderbolt port will cause some issues if any peripherals are attached and active when the machine goes to sleep. After this happens any subsequent sleep cycle might be affected and an NVRAM reset with subsequent variable setting dance outlined above will be necessary, again. It seems advisable in such cases to either prevent machine sleep or unplug any hardware on the Thunderbolt port before letting the machine sleep.

Within the restrictions outlined at the start of this answer: Most users report complete success.

---

### Hardware mods/hacks

Several ways available now, some bad, some good.

Bad solution: A very cheap hardware modification is available at/from [RealMacMods:](https://realmacmods.com/macbook-2011-radeon-gpu-disable/)
While they use a relatively complicated way of setting the necessary EFI variable with linux the following has the advantage of cutting the core voltage to the dGPU completely by removing just one tiny resistor! (Pictures at the link)

> On this reboot it is essential that you boot once into safe mode (hold Shift throughout boot), and then choose shutdown (not restart) from the menu.
> Do this safe boot with the R8911 resistor in place. Without this SAFE BOOT, the next steps may not work.
> Do no more boots until you complete the next steps.
> The safe boot clears OS level GPU preferences, that may interfere with the following process.
> This will now cause your MacBook Pro to stop switching to the Radeon automatically, but it will still draw power, create heat, and be visible to the OS.
> We discovered that simply removing 1 resistor will resolve this.
> The resistor can also be replaced with a switch, in case you need to turn your radeon back on for any reason.
> The placement of this resistor varies between logic board models.
> The resistor in question is R8911 on the 17″ MBP and R8911 on the 15″ MBP
> a 1 Ohm resistor that provides a current path to the ISL6263C DC to DC Converter.
> This resistor controls power to the Voltage Regulator that provides the Core Voltage to the Radeon GPU. Simply put, no core voltage, no GPU.
> You will find the resistor just to the right of a cooling fan (in the above orientation). It will be near the ISL Voltage converter chip. This is the chip we will be disabling.
> Just remove it. The preferred method is a professional reflow station, but an iron and a steady hand will get you where you need to be.  If you used flux to remove it (not needed), make sure you clean up with a little Alcohol or other suitable solvent.
> That is basically it. Next time you boot up you will notice your GPU defect issue is gone, and you will no longer see the AMD GPU as installed hardware.

I have not tested this but it should eliminate any need to care for the kexts and also solve any issues regarding sleep, wakeup, hibernation, reboot etc.
Caveat for considering this method: since it also seems to rely on having this NVRAM variable set it is likely *absolutely essential* to have a fully automated method in place to set this variable without any user intervention. (Like a linux stick that makes the necessary changes) Otherwise an NVRAM reset might practically brick the machine. The vendor suggests to protect from accidental NVRAM resets via password and if a reset was made to call them for a 'procedure'.

If bitten by this method, ending up with just a black screen: it seems possible to remotely access the machine with VNC or ssh, so *if these are setup beforehand,* it may indeed a not so bad option after all, as the nvram variable can bet set in this way. Remember: Untested internet story.

### Permanent, reliable and cheap hardware solution!

Dosdude1 has found a solution that looks like the holy grail for this problem: [Permanently Disable 2011 15"/17" MacBook Pro Dedicated GPU - gMux IC Bypass](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/permanently-disable-2011-15-17-macbook-pro-dedicated-gpu-gmux-ic-bypass.2134019/)

> - Option A, which will be detailed below, is to hard-wire the LVDS output lines from the integrated graphics LVDS output lines straight to the lines connecting to the display.
> - Option B would be to re-program the gMux IC (which is simply a Lattice LFXP2 micro-controller), with a custom firmware to disable the GPU switching functionality. I may experiment with this in the future, but doing so requires special hardware that I don't have. This would, of course, be the optimal solution, though.

This is almost easy. All that's needed are [various lengths of wire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ls3v.jpg). To get a glimpse:
[image]
[on youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbXb0gfRxEY)

The 'bad solution' from above is now made into an almost professional and pre-made hardware solution, eliminating the previous 'badness' of that approach:

> [Tiresias (the GPUkiller):](http://www.cmizapper.com/products/tiresias-gpukiller.html)
> The Tiresias is a small board that can be soldered onto the motherboard of the MacBook Pro 15-inch or 17-inch 2011 (Early or Late) models.
> These are all the models that have the 820-2914-A, 820-2914-B, 820-2915-A or 820-2915-B motherboard.
> The 820-2914 and 820-2915 board has two GPUs. The internal (Intel) GPU that is part of the PCH, and an external (discrete) AMD GPU. It is the external GPU that fails  in 'a small percentage of MacBook Pro systems' (Apple-speak for: 'very many'). The Tiresias writes the 'gpu-power-prefs' nvram-variable to the ROM so that the Mac does not use the (dead) external (discrete) AMD GPU anymore. If the user clears the NVRAM (PRAM) there is no problem as the Tiresias will write the record again, and the Mac will work again.
>
> This makes this the ideal solution to bring a 820-2914 or 820-2915 with dead GPU back to life. Installation is easy (no wires to solder). You will need to mount a very small board onto the motherboard. An experienced technician can do this in minutes. Other than that R8911 should be removed to turn off power to the dead GPU. This saves energy, generating less heat and conserving battery life. Removing R8911 also prevents the Mac from getting confused by the dead GPU because even with the GPU turned off it will still try to talk to the dead GPU. Depending on what internal contacts in the GPU are ruptured this might confuse or even crash the Mac.
> Mac OS X 10.13 High Sierra is also supported. To solve the issue of the backlight not coming back on after sleep also remove R9704 and connect R9704 pin 2 to C9711 pin 1.
>
> OS X 10.6 - 10.12 (Sierra)
> The backlight slider (in System Preferences) and the backlight keys (F1 and F2) work. System sleep works. Video out on the Thunderbolt port does not work, but all other functions of the Thunderbolt port do work.
>
> OS X 10.13 (High Sierra)
> As far as we know 10.13 (High Sierra) offers no advantages over 10.12 (Sierra). Apple totally redid the video drivers in High Sierra, and seem to have made a mess of it. The backlight controls will not work. And worse, after the machine wakes up from sleep the backlight is not turned back on at all.
> To solve the issue of the backlight not coming back on after sleep remove R9704 and connect R9704 pin 2 to C9711 pin 1. This sets the backlight to full brightness. The down-side is that with this modification the brightness will also be on full brightness with the oldes OS's.
> Tiresias for 820-2915 (15-Inch) Quantity one (1) Including shipping (world wide) 60 EURO.

> [image] [image] [image]

---

#### Update for a one-stop software solution

This hack seems to have been cast *partially* into an application related to the hardware hack! On the one hand this application is more universal than the solution above, as it seems to handle also NVidia cards, that is: it is for disabling all discrete CPUs in all Macs.

Alas, this app by dosdude1 is not well documented.
The readme says that it would set the NVRAM variable, move *all* graphic acceleration drivers, and then install a launchdaemon to handle updates and ensure that the variable stays set.

Not tested and not endorsed — if you already have followed the procedure outlined above!
But if the hack above didn't work at some point for you or seems just to daunting to begin with, then you might try this:

[dosdude1: Other, undocumented software that I've written is stored here: MacBook Pro dGPU Disabler.zip](http://dosdude1.com/apps/MacBook%20Pro%20dGPU%20Disabler.zip)

You might have to look into the procedure above again, as the application seems to miss out on improving the thermal management part (if you modify the hardware by removing the transistor this becomes mood: mix and match).
If someone tests this out, please give feedback here via comments or an edit.

---

[Update 2019: 20$ solution](https://computeco.de/Demux) that uses a 64bit Windows computer and a  Lattice HW-USBN-2A ICSP FPGA programmer to apply a custom firmware to the  gMux IC. Dosdude1 claims this to be 'perfect' solution, meaning that even under HighSierra and Mojave battery life, temperature, brightness control and wake/sleep work as expected. Using that solution is permanent and makes everything above obsolete.
But this new solution is not free and requires hardware in the form of a Windows PC and the programmer); as well as currently soldering a few wires temporarily to the logic board.)

[Update June 2020]: [This gMUX Bypass with native brightness control](http://advancedreworks.com/forum/showthread.php/gmux-bypass-native-brightness-control-3680.html) is a cheaper (opensource) version of the Dosdude1 hardware hack. [GitHub: gMUXBypass](https://github.com/ayilm1/gMUXBypass)

Comment: "but the system doesn't know how to power-management the failed AMD-chip." What does this mean?

Comment: @natario From numerous reports and personal experience: not loading the kext at all=GPU is idling at hipower->~60-85°C; delayed loading the kext=power-management is active, saves battery and temp->~15-50°C.

Comment: Thanks. I had already removed all AMD kexts actually. But I can kextload all of them on boot, right?

Comment: Actually, what's the point of removing them if we already asked to boot with integrated GPU? I thought that the reason for this was to not let it use discrete GPU during normal runtime. But if you suggest to re-add them at boot, then my thought does not make much sense anymore

Comment: In theory. They are somehow interdependent to certain degrees. It's really best to allow the system to pick those for themselves, i.e.  have all of them ready in case they are loaded dynamically, for upgrades etc. **Except** the X3000. Power management needs the drivers, but X3000 *too early on boot* will hang it.

Comment: I see. It's not 100% clear in your answer when you say 'except one', 'just one', that you are referring to the specific X3000 and not to 'one of the AMD kexts' in general, you might want to edit that. Thanks, great answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. My laptop is having this issue again (having had the motherboard replaced 4 times so far). I haven't had any lockups on boot or during use since applying this hack (on 10.11.6) *but* I've noticed that the computer no longer goes to sleep properly when I close the lid. Instead, the entire computer seems to shut down. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: @Twitch_City Know this problem. No real fix, but see updated answer (*1). // Try another SMC reset and just  re-apply variable. If this fails: put it to sleep with command & avoid the lid before sleep light pulses. Upgrade to 10.12. If all fails: keep temps high & X3000kext out.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the quick response. It is weird behaviour - seems to happen when I use lid-close *and* when I use the Apple menu item to go to sleep. The display turns off and it takes about 30 seconds for the computer to sleep. It does go to sleep (pulsing light) and it also tries to wake up (the keyboard lights up, the pulsing light stops) - but the display refuses to come back on.

Comment: So I fiddled around with the LoadX3000.sh script and commenting out the gpuswitch line had no effect on the sleep behaviour. If I don't load the script on boot, the computer is able to sleep and wake as normal. If I load the script manually after boot, the laptop appears to wake (screen turns on) but then it hangs until it reboots. I guess I will keep temps high until I'm able to carve out some time to do an OS upgrade.

Comment: Worked on a MacBook Pro early 2011 that's on its fourth GPU/motherboard replacement - thanks!

Comment: I had already upgraded to High Sierra before my most recent problem, and I have not noticed any consistent problems relate to sleeping and waking the MacBook Pro. That said, there have been a few times when I’ve opened it up and it has appeared to boot from scratch, but I put that down to the battery having completely discharged while it was left asleep. I’ll try to pay more attention to it and report here if I notice anything relevant.

Comment: Both with and without the X3000 kext loaded, I have only seen GPU temperatures of 50-60 degrees depending on load. I'm basing this on the readings reported by iStat Menus under [GPU Die - Analog]. This was even with the CPU core temperatures up to 99 degrees this evening importing photos into Lightroom (X3000 kext loaded at that time). I have also not experienced any issues with sleeping and waking, regardless of how I sleep, whether closing the lid or using the menu command.

Comment: @LangLangC When I write  `nvram boot-args="-v agc=0"`  , I get sandboxviolation: nvram - allow(0) message. Is it normal?

Comment: @Tarek Yes, alas, that is normal.  You need to either disable SIP or issue it from a RecoveryMode. Setting will stick from there. – Honestly, should I make that clearer in the answer? If you get a violation you seem to be *not in SingleUserRecovery* (the Recovery is vital in the howto above). Or do you get it in a RecoveryMode? That would be new (=not normal).

Comment: @LangLangC I get it in the SingleUserRecovery mode.

Comment: @Tarek Strange. You seem to be on High Sierra. I do not know if they have tightened that further up lately. Do you have an older system bootable? From Yosemite it works always; in Sierra as described above (and from both the setting will stick). Otherwise I'd suggest to disable SIP and try that again (then perhaps also from a normal boot?). (Leaving `agc` out is not catastrophic, I ran the Mac for month without it before finding this trick. Improvement varies only from 'a bit' to 'OK, *almost* great') Radical chic would be to use a linux stick and set the variable from there…

Comment: Just had a bit of a mess updating to 10.13.4 and got stuck in a boot loop, but careful application of the instruction steps here sorted it out again for me. Initially after fixing the boot loop my dock was no longer transparent, but it came good after re-applying `nvram boot-args="-v agc=0"` - not really sure if that's what did it, or just another reboot.

Comment: After a couple of months trying to get my Late 2011 17" mbp back into the land of the living, I _finally_ discovered that the discrete GPU issue was the culprit.  Honestly @LangLangC in all my years in IT, I've never seen such a logically-written and comprehensive explanation of a well-crafted solution, with undeniably-expert level detail.  And all from an altruistic desire to help others.  I'm typing this on my revived MBP, and while I know that you didn’t do this to make money, you saved me potentially thousands so I’ll PM you in the hope I can buy you a beer via Patreon etc. Thanks so much.

Comment: For the record, as of 10.13.4 the kexts related to AMD GPUs are: com.apple.kext.AMDLegacySupport (1.6.6), com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller (1.6.6), com.apple.kext.AMDLegacyFramebuffer (1.6.6) and com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX3000 (1.6.6).

Comment: First off thanks a lot for this excellent guide, it really helped!
Re: "Apparent hangs on shutdown are usually just very long delays that will shutdown, eventually, cleanly and successfully.", in my case the machine wasn't able to shutdown (tried leaving it in "shutting down state" the whole night, never happened) which was worrying me to have to force shutdown all the times. By commenting out the line `kextload  /System/Library/Extensions-off/AMDRadeonX3000.kext` I'm now able to shutdown again normally on Yosemite. If I'll end up updating the OS I'll try to enable that line and try it again.

Comment: Worked for me on mbp 15inch early 2011 High Sierra! You are a lifesaver!

Comment: Just reporting in that the 10.13.5 update left me unable to boot and the procedure above allowed me to recover as usual. My dock was opaque again (as it was after the 10.13.4 update), but returned to translucent after a reboot - presumably this behaviour is due to not having com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX3000 loaded on the first boot after re-applying this fix.

Comment: Worked for me on a 17" early 2011 running Sierra! External display doesn't work but better than a giant paperweight! Do note (for the noobs like me), you need to type `reboot` after the initial SIP disable `csrutil disable` and after the gpu nvram changes in recovery. I wasn't sure how to reboot from the recovery terminal, and tried hard powering down, but the SIP change did not persist that way.

Comment: Wow this is totally unbelievable. My macbook was a brick until I did all this. Thank you so much! Not it is running really well.

Comment: After the High Sierra 10.13.6 software update it's not possible to start in single-user-recovery by pressing cmd-R-S as it just enter single-user mode, making it impossible to disable SIP. Anyone knows how to boot in single-user-recovery in on recent versions?

Comment: @LucaBonavita If that is indeed the case you should ask that as a sepeerate Q here. –– In your current case: just use regular SingleUser (Cmd+s) or RecoveryMode (Cmd-R), then issue the commands in GUI Terminal. That works, it is just much slower to do then the method above.

Comment: @LangLangC thanks. Problem is, cmd-R tries to open the graphic interface, which is in this case it's not possible to be seen as the graphic card is broken (I get a blue screen), and with cmd-S (single-user) it says "Enabling and disabling services is not supported in single-user mode" and if you try "csrutil disable" it replies "csrutil: failed to modify system integrity configuration. This tool needs to be executed from the Recovery OS", so I'm stuck there.

Comment: Asked at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332587/single-user-recovery-mode-on-high-sierra-10-13-6 to reduce noise here.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful compilation of all possible solutions for our beloved 2011 mbp. I resurrected my dead notebook with the nvram and kext removal method on High Sierra now updated to 10.13.6 . Everything works as it should, the notebook runs cooler, brightness control works fine, sleep too works fine. 

Today I connected thunderbolt cable to another working mac in Target disk mode, but nothing. Rebooted 2011 mbp to TDM, nothing on other mac. I feel the thunderbolt data connection is through GPU, so its broken. Unlike some mentions of 'TB should work'. Will test it with eGPU now

Comment: Thank you! Just revived my MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2011) (MacBookPro8,3), running High Sierra 10.13.6. The MacBook is already on its second motherboard/GPU, and the first one failed just as the replacement program got started. Have ordered a replacement laptop now, but until that arrives everything seems to work fine using this fix.

Comment: @Raj Thx for your edit. I just did this hack with regular Recovery on a 10.13.6  machine without nvram variable *and* without issues. Can you please confirm that no matter what you tried, you were stuck on white screen with cmd+r *without* the nvram variable set?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE PRECISE GUIDE.
LOVELY, it works, though as mentiones sometimes shutdown hangs, but that's just a minor issue... Concerning the hard-wiring solution I miss another suggestion: I mean, if somebody already messes with microelectronics and permanentlz disables the dGPU, he/she as well could re-weld the graphic chip to the board (because most of the times it's not that the dGPU dies but that the  connections overheat and brake). But if the dGPU has died, it could be also replaced by the same person and a new one re-welded to the Motherboard.

Comment: A quick note that Security Update 2018-003 broke my 10.13.6 MacBook Pro and I had to follow the process here again.

Comment: I believe the comment by @WillBuck should be integrated in the answer. Namely, after '''csrutil disable''' one needs to type '''reboot''' and afterwards keep Cmd+r+s pressed so the reboot occurs in single user recovery mode. Otherwise on step 9 one gets an "Operation not permitted" error.

Comment: @LangLangC THANKS for a such complete and MBP-life saving guide. Couple of things: 1. As @Tarek, I got the `SandboxViolation: nvram(3) - allow(0)` error, but I'm on 10.12.6, Single User Recovery mode, and `csrutil status` does say it's disabled. Any clue?  —— 2. I'm in verbose all the time now (as set in args) – safe to disable it?

Comment: @Joan Verbose is 'safe' to turn off. ('On' = easier to spot hangs and causes for that on boot, your choice) / The "violation": try it from regular Recovery. That should work as well, just slower… (or leave out agc – its effect is small)

Comment: I've been on 10.13.6 for a while, but just lost the use of my brightness adjustment keys today. Following this process in full yet again has restored them, as @MayankChandak also reported above. I can't say what event triggered them not working when they had been, but I'm posting this news in case it helps anyone else. For the record, my 2011 MBP on 10.13.6 no longer allows SingleUserRecovery but Terminal via the graphical Recovery mode still permits turning off SIP via `csrutil disable`.

Comment: Graphical recovery mode might not work too, as it did for me. However, in the last version of High Sierra, it is still possible to boot to single user recovery mode. It just needs good timing. The trick is to first enable recovery mode by pressing cmd+R and immediately after it is recognized the cmd+S command for the single user mode. The exact moment has to be figured out by the user. If cmd+R+S are pressed at the same time, only single user mode will be activated. If first cmd+R is pressed and cmd+S is pressed too late, graphical recovery mode is loaded.

Comment: @KendallLister Another recent finding, I can successfully run a TB3 eGPU with the 2011 MBP , even after a failed dGPU

Comment: @LangLangC Been happy with this for months now. Just an issue that occurs more and more regurarly: when waking up from sleep, keyboard backlight goes on but not the screen, and it reboots by itself after a while (if I do not force it). Can it be related to agc not being changed (#comment457154_295805)? And maybe the macOS update I've been ignoring so far may fix it? — Thanks again a lot.

Comment: @joan Setting agc=0 is slight improvement over all. But the root causes for wake-problems is letting it go to sleep with cables plugged in (esp Thunderbolt) & hardware triggered sleep. To avoid that, unplug TB before sleep & try to always use software (AppleMenu) to trigger sleep (not lid-close, wait until it's snoring lights). A slight temp fix 4you *now* is resetting SMC and NVRAM, starting over with this guide (but only setting NVRAM variable + agc again; the rest is in place / remember to set startup disk in SysPrefs). Not perfect but reduces the issues for a while.

Comment: @LangLangC I get the same behaviour as Joan on opening the lid after sleeping, i.e. keyboard backlight comes on but screen doesn't. After holding down the power button to force my MacBook Pro to power off and then restarting, I get a warning about an error with the details: "GPU Panic: mux-regs 2 3 7f 0 0 0 severity 3 WS-ready 1 switch-state 0 IG FBs 1 EG FBs 0:0 power-state 4 3D idle HDA idle system-state 2 power-level 20:20 connect-change 0 : UH eHlPH
E0L H(L @ H HH : GPU is not found. PCI config access fails!!!" I'm posting this in case it can help improve this solution even further.

Comment: I have recently started facing the same issue that @Joan and Kendall explained. I haven't updated my Mac recently and I'm not quite sure what has caused this.

Comment: @LangLangC have you got any suggestions for mounting a read-only APFS drive?

Comment: I needed to remove `AMD6000Controller.kext` as well to get it working

Comment: Thank you so much ! My small contribution : I also had the shutdown issue (Sierra, black screen and no shut down) and fixed it by just rebooting the computer once in safe mode (SHIFT key at reboot). Then the shutdown worked again !

Comment: Thanks a ton for this helpful and detailed explanation which has (for the time being) brought back my MacBook Pro to life!
A question I had related to using SMCFacnControl. For some reason, the settings are not being retained, even after filling the Admin password details when saving the changes. Neither is the app launching on startup.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: So which one of these solutions will enable again my HDMI port so I can plug in external monitor?

Comment: Step #4 stuck with me now... because I got csrutil: failed to modify system integrity configuration. This tool needs to be executed from the Recovery OS

Comment: @jeand'arme None of them unfortunately.  Disabling the GPU also disables the external graphics ports.  The only solution for you would be to pay to have the AMD chip replaced.  I was quoted $150 this week by a Mac repair shop, which I think is very reasonable.

Comment: Thank you!  This is great, was just about to throw in the towel with this MAC.  I have a slightly different swizzle on all of this that seems to be working, initially at least. I have disabled sip, and used 'sudo nvram boot-args="-v"'
and 'sudo nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00'  from single user mode, and then boot my mac in 'safe' mode by holding down the shift key.   Not sure what else I'm losing in safe mode, but everything, with the exception of external display, now seems to work.  Of course the intel chip is slower than the radeon.

Comment: @AndrewAtrens In SafeMode you loose all graphics accel, not even Intel. Try booting in regular mode after this *whole* process is finished and be quite pleasantly amazed that an accelerated IntelGPU is performing quite well. (Tho, your external display will stay gone with this hack)

Comment: The June 2020 update comment that links http://advancedreworks.com/forum/showthread.php/gmux-bypass-native-brightness-control-3680.html seems to be returning a 404 page with no Wayback Machine archive. Does anybody know what it was in reference to?

Comment: @TSGM Dammit. Thought I archived.org the page… But it's a known issue: https://github.com/ayilm1/gMUXBypass/issues/1

Comment: Couldn't steps 7-12 be performed in single-user-recovery-mode (along with the LoginHook stuff) by modifying the files available at /Volumes/Your-HD-name/ without needing to reboot into single-user-mode?

Comment: How would things like loginhook work if one is using Bootcamp and booting to Windows?

Comment: @j-beda yes some of the steps in the guide can be combined. If you know what you are doing. I just did that and it's working.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Hi, thank you for this. Really. The followup question is that do you suppose this is a long-term solution (with the known compromises like no external monitor, etc.)?

Comment: @MayankChandak Hi Mayank, Which eGPU do you use, any recommendations? Does it still work to connect to an external monitor via the TB port?

Comment: @Yogesch Sonnet eGPU with RX 580. TB port only works as TB port, no longer as displayport

Comment: I got two MacBook Pros in the summer of 2011 (if I had known to just wait for the much better 2012!!). Both had GPU issues and had the motherboards replaced by Apple, but the GPU issues came back within 2 months. One of the laptop had the motherboard replaced again. Afterwards I installed gfxCardStatus and each time after boot, I selected "Integrated Only" and treated it like a senior citizen. But on Jan 1, 2021, an ominous green column appeared when I had to transfer 2500 photos from my iPhone. I wish Apple could have reimbursed us for all the pain, and the replacement not fixing anything.

Comment: @HaoQiLi Yeah, almost same story here. Apple's behavior successfully convinced me to no longer use Macs after 10 years of having a Mac as my primary device.

Comment: I had trouble getting to single user recovery mode in the above instructions, but this worked well:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332587/single-user-recovery-mode-on-high-sierra-10-13-6

Comment: Has anyone had any luck with the sleep/wake issue on >=10.13? I needed to update from sierra to catalina (10.15) for some required software compatibility, and now it cannot wake from sleep (or is it just the backlight does not turn back on?).

Comment: @user2561747 Up until Mojave (Catalina: IDK) I do not think that sleep/wake is primarily caused by any OS version. Happened from 10.10 upward in various ways, incl. 'works as expected', but with circumstances like pro/con. Try patience: start with clean NVRAM, clean hack; disconnect all peripherals before sleep, do not let it sleep with thunderbolt attached, avoid lid-close sleep, issue soft sleep (like via menu). If all that doesn't help, or indeed is Catalina-specific (please test against .14): please ask a new question here (with your answer; esp. if you do find it to be Catalina specific!)

Comment: @LаngLаngС thanks for the quick reply and very helpful guide!! I actually have the 2012 model with a broken NVIDIA dGPU, so this issue may be specific to that model (although most of this guide is still applicable!). I did try a clean NVRAM reset and hack (which requires using single-user mode blind, but thankfully with a script and tab-completion, it still works well). I unfortunately don't have time to test on 10.14, and need 10.15 for compatibility with remote proctoring software for an upcoming exam. I posted a new, more detailed question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/421083/203559

Comment: What, exactly, does the `agc=0` boot arg accomplish? I can find lots or resources that endorse this setting, some referring directly or indirectly back to your answer here, but nowhere do I find a real good explanation of what it is for.

Comment: I'm dealing with a machine where this was done previously but the NVRAM was reset since and the machine now boots to a black screen (it's not just the backlight that's failed). I think I'm able to boot into single user mode using `cmd+S` and blindly run commands (e.g. `reboot` works) but nothing happens when I run the `nvram` command and reboot afterwards, the machine just reboots to a black screen again. I've tried `sudo nvram` just in case, and it didn't help either... any thoughts?

Comment: @jsavn If the backlight borked, then what's the point? Sometimes these machines really die. Couple of 2cts though: A really strong external light src may make things a bit more visible. Typing these cmds is prone to error (try & try again; if the script I suggested above is not present. It's much easier.) Try an external login (ssh or something, via ethernet, such service need enabling[perhaps boot the removed drive in a 'good mac', set the prefs]). Since hardware issues: try a usb2video, try a hw-solution, a repair(-shop?). In this state, I'd also try seriously  a reflow/baking oven method.

Comment: @LangLangC thanks for your suggestions - I ended up solving it with a combination of reflow and ssh which was enabled, luckily. I'm pretty sure it wouldn't connect to the network prior to the reflow, but it works now in any case! Thanks a lot for the writeup. Here's to another 10 years...

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that you're unable to move those files it's probably the System Integrity Protection that's stopping you. I'm assuming you're on El Capitan or Sierra.

- Shutdown your laptop.
- Press Command + R and then the power button to boot into recovery mode.
- Click the Utilities menu and select Terminal.
- Type `csrutil disable` and press return.
- Close the Terminal app and restart out of recovery mode.
- Now try booting back into Single-User mode and try to `mv` command.

If that worked re-enable SIP:

- Shutdown your laptop.
- Press Command + R and then the power button to boot into recovery mode.
- Click the Utilities menu and select Terminal.
- Type csrutil enable and press return.
- Close the Terminal app and restart out of recovery mode.

Comment: @klanomath thank you for your quick response. But the only mode I can get throught is the single user mode. It freez in recovery mode even in the Internet recovery mode.

Comment: @GhaziMarzouk **Snacking_IT** answered your question! I just edited it a little bit...

Comment: **@Snacking_IT**   thank you for your quick response. But the only mode I can get throught is the single user mode. It freez in recovery mode even in the Internet recovery mode

Comment: Just as an update, in @LangLangC's answer, I was unable to disable SIP on El Capitan during Step 1.3 and 1.4, as Single User Recovery only mounts the drive as read-only. The above approach (booting into recovery mode instead) does work, so this information is useful to include.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/300460 from https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/251859/langlangc. I followed it when I had this issue in last Sep2018. However I struggled a bit to figure out the exact delta steps to be performed for the second time, when I came across the same issue yesterday again when I did the OSX Security update 2019-003. So, thought of putting down exactly those steps thinking of those users who might come across this issue for a second time. Once again, huge thanks to langlangc for the original one.

I was on OSX 10.13.6 at the time when I did the update.

1. Restart in single-user mode by press&hold Cmd+S (Cmd+R won't load giving the white screen. Actually, `langlangc` had asked me to confirm this in Sep2018; but I couldn't reply then as I don't have permission to comment)

   - Run `sh /force-iGPU-boot.sh`
2. Restart in recovery mode by press&hold Cmd+r

   - Run these commands. In fact, I put these into a small script file /force-iGPU-boot_without_sudo.sh.
     `csrutil disable
     nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00
     nvram boot-args="-v"`
3. Restart in single-user mode by press&hold Cmd+s

   - Ensure an existing `/System/Library/Extensions-off` folder is removed after taking a backup
   - Run these commands. Again, I put these into a small script file /move_out_amd_kext.sh

     `/sbin/mount -uw /
     mkdir -p /System/Library/Extensions-off
     mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX3000.kext  /System/Library/Extensions-off/
     touch /System/Library/Extensions/`
   - Enter `nvram boot-args="agc=0"`
   - Enter `reboot` to boot it normally.

Everything else should be working as expected as you would have done all the other necessary steps when you got it working for the first time. All the best.

### Update 12 August 2019

I used to depend upon the software based solution suggested by @LangLangC. However, the recent update in August found the normal booting hung on the progress bar. I can get through safe boot mode, though but will find screen flickering a lot.

### Update 14 August 2019

Booted successfully when I disabled the SIP in recovery-mode. I can't remember if I have done in the past - but now I guess I may have.

I wasted a lot of time suspecting many different reasons - including the GPU problem getting worse, or potential bugs with 10.13.6 security update 2019-004.

However, now I noticed that it booted this time even with the problematic `/System/Library/Extensions/AMDRadeonX3000.kext` in place !!!

### Update 11 November 2019

The `AMD6000Controller.kext` is necessary to get the brightness control back to work as usual. That kext has to be present at `/System/Library/Extensions/`.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you mean with "2nd time"? The above looks as if you had NVRAM/PRAM reset in the process. Or is this indeed what you did while being with a working hack on 10.13 and just applied the recent SecUpdate? (The SecUpdate itself should do nothing to invalidate the hack itself, but install a working AMD.kext in the – for the hack – wrong location, and hence needs to be moved). Or from the other side: was your NVRAM reset during the update?

Comment: I was already on a working hack on 10.13.6 which was done in last Sep2018 following your answer. Then applied the security update yesterday after which I am stuck again with white screen. I never play around with KEXT files unless I do have to follow your instructions to fix the white screen issue after the security update. With just step-1(1st single-user mode) did not fix issue, so I had to go into step-2(recovery mode) subsequently to step-3(single-user mode again).

Comment: I just updated my High Sierra volume with the latest 2019-005 security update. The process bar got stuck on the reboot, so I waited for the fans to stop and rebooted my MBP manually in single-user mode and followed your guide. Worked fine! A few questions though: why do you have to repeat the NVRAM hack in step 2? it's already in the `/force-iGPU-boot.sh` script no? and my `Extensions-off` directory was already in place, I just moved the new `AMDRadeonX3000.kext` and called it `AMDRadeonX3000v2.kext`. Seems better to keep and load the original as stated in @LangLangC guide I guess.

Comment: @aroom The above repeats a few redundant steps, doing no harm, just a belt & suspenders approach. The key to updates is with NVRAM in place a *working* X3000 hangs booting. Quite often Apple shipped a defective kext that *depended* on one original install, all deltas missing a crucial file. (For optimal results, we had to mv old kext into place, then update, then mv to Ext-off again) Now that Apple finally fixed that, it is best to use the newest kext from update, matching the version numbers in the update. With SIP off, just boot SafeMode and mv to Ext-off, deleting the previous version.

Comment: Has anyone ever reenabled the dGPU setting? What would be the opposite of `nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00`?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot thank @LangLangC enough for this response.  This has just resuscitated 2 machines.  A few curve balls are worthy *only* as a complement to the above:

- one machine was on Mavericks (10.9.5), so yes SIP related commands could be discarded.  However, since the AMDRadeon issue starting arising (and your truly resetting galore the SMC and PRAM), I had ended up generating a split screen somehow with a thin high vertical line as a cursor.  It required two cycles of phase 1 to overcome.
- a second machine was on High Sierre 10.13.6. `csrutil disable` (point 3 above) would not run; this was tried twice with distinct disks, with identical results.  Only Recovery mode allowed the command to proceed successfully

  `Cmd` + `r`
  [Be Pa.tien.t.  The recovery partition has to start up with the GUI (I kept the keys pressed until the language choice dialog box that appears when installing system for a first time appears) ] Select the terminal under the `Utility` menu. This allowed the call. Proceed with the instructions

  `nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00`
  `nvram boot-args="-v"`
  then reboot

  `shutdown -r now` 
  and proceed to step 8 above.  ( I may have done an extra round of the above two commands; I lost track - but no harm done)  ...  After step 11

  `touch /System/Library/Extensions/`
  will actually cycle through a couple of reboots and verbose messages before presenting a crisp, grey apple. [Continue with the patience exercise.]

I second the suggestion of downloading and activating smcFanControl or similar before dealing with heat management; seeing the temperature drop is more enlightening than waiting for the fan to spin down.

- once going, change energy saving settings for the automated `computer sleep` settings: it played 2020_shuffle with my screen upon waking. So under power adapter, never put computer sleep (the screen can go black though).
  I have not tried lid down, but I believe this can be an issue.  If the screen does get garbled, I found that log-out hotkeys  `Shift`+ `Cmd` + `Q` will invariably reset the video to its expected state.

Some flickering will occur; I guess this is practical proof of the necessity for two graphics chips. no big deal though.

- finally, it dawned on me that since this is a software solution, popping the boot disk with directories and files already prepared and installing in another machine (if that's an option) might make the process faster to edit the arching and shell scripts.  Will attempt later. *attempted* but failed as step 8 did not seem to register.

Notes:

- external video is not accessible as designed,  but doing so via USB port is.
- Bootcamp also is a casualty.