# GPU-defect Macbook Pro 2011 does not accept csrutil disable anymore (10.13.6)

Tags: macos, gpu, sip

I have a failing Macbook Pro and have deactivated the discrete GPU by doing something [editors note: help us help you by detailing what modifications you made to deactivate the GPU].

Now on this machine, once I updated to macOS 10.13.6
it does not accept the "csrutil disable" anymore which leads to the fact
that I am not able to go through this process:

[GPU problem - Boot Hangs on Grey Screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen/295805#295805)

I already asked on several other platforms but nobody can explain me why it is not working anymore.
With the following Command (CMD-R-S) it seems that it does not go into the Recovery Single User mode and thus I have no sufficient rights to perform this action (csrutil disable).
Can somebody please help and tell me how to fix this?

Best regards

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83245/discussion-on-question-by-robert-yarborough-gpu-defect-macbook-pro-2011-does-not).

Comment: There are major points of confusion here. See chat and this might need to be closed for Robert to edit more simply what’s going on here. It’s not clear if he keeps having problems trying to deactivate a GPU since each time he applies a software update, the os is back as designed or if there are cascading hardware failures.

Comment: Just had a defect MBP with 10.13.6 hands on. R+S seems indeed inaccessible now. But regular RecoveryMode (Cmd+R) worked and accepted csrutil commands. Please [edit] this question according to whether that worked for you or not.

Comment: @bmike This is strange. Once comments are moved to chat, I was told to continue commenting there in general. Yet you continue to comment here. & Looks like you are not pingable in that chat? This is not "how could you?" More: Wouldn't it be a good idea for your handle to be pingable in chat then? –– This comment is probably no longer needed once you've read it.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue but did not have to use another computer or usb drive.
Via: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336676/302408

I was having the same issue. This is how I fixed it.

As we are not able to get to single-user-recovery mode by holding Cmd+R+S at startup to run `csrutil disable`, it is not taking you to SingleUserRecoveryMode.

I run the nvram command here in SingleUserMode

`nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00`

Then reboot

`reboot`

On reboot hold Cmd+R and it will take us to the GUI recovery mode. There click on Utility and open Terminal, here we can run the csrutil command.

`csrutil disable`

Then again make sure to run the nvram command then reboot

`nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00`

`reboot`

Boot into SingleUserMode Cmd+S to continue with the kext moving procedure. once done, go back to GUI recovery to re-enable SIP `csrutil enable`, then reboot once morew.

Once the Mac fully boots run nvram one last time as sudo

`sudo nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00`

Now do multiple reboots to test the machine boots back up properly. I have no issues now.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to quote essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

This answer would require another computer and a flash drive. Also, you would have to either remove the internal drive or have have the ability to connect the Mac to another Mac in target disk mode.

> Note: I assume your Mac has only one internal drive, so the flash drive would be `disk1`.

BTW: I tested what I could using my 2011 iMac with macOS 10.13.6.

The boot manager rEFInd can disable SIP. Also, rEFInd can be configured to boot in text only mode.

1. You would need another computer to download the [rEFInd zip file](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html). Look for the link `A USB flash drive image file`. On my Mac, downloading created a folder named `refind-flashdrive-0.11.3` in my `Downloads` folder.
2. Next you would use the `dd` command to transfer the rEFInd image to the flash drive. I used the commands given below. Here, I assume the `refind-flashdrive-0.11.3.img`  file is in the `~/Downloads/refind-flashdrive-0.11.3` folder.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/refind-flashdrive-0.11.3
   diskutil unmountdisk disk1
   sudo dd if=refind-flashdrive-0.11.3.img of=/dev/disk1
   ```
3. Mount the EFI partition on the flash drive. For macOS, the command is given below.

   ```
   sudo diskutil mount disk1s1
   ```
4. Add the following lines to the end of the `refind.conf` file. This will cause rEFInd to boot in text only mode. You can read the `refind.conf` file for more information. I choose a value of `2` arbitrarily.

   ```
   textonly
   textmode 2
   ```
5. Plug the flash drive into your Mac.
6. I assume you can not use the Mac Startup Manager because this would require a graphics mode display. However, if you assume the default item in the menu is first, then you can select to boot from the USB flash drive without using the screen. Follow this procedure:

   A. Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key. This will invoke the Startup Manager. You will have to hold the key down until you assume the Startup Manager is running.

   B. Press the <kbd>←</kbd> key once. This should select the last item on the Startup Manager menu. The USB flash drive will always be the last item.

   C. Press the <kbd>return</kbd> to boot from the USB flash drive.

   If the computer does not boot from the flash drive, then try pressing the <kbd>←</kbd> key more than once.
7. When the rEFInd menu appears, select `Change SIP Policy`, then press <kbd>return</kbd> key.
8. Wait for the screen to flash.
9. Select `About rEFInd` to confirm SIP is disabled.

Comment: thank you! i put the image in my downloads folder but the terminal returns "dd: refind-flashdrive-0.11.3.img: No such file or directory"

Comment: @RobertYarborough Did you extract the zip? If so, try using Etcher (a GUI tool for imaging files) to image the file to a USB instead of `dd`.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tested my answer, I had SIP disabled when I entered the bless command. So, I needed to change my answer. Sorry that new answer is not as easy to implement.

Comment: @David Anderson

Comment: After some thought, I again changed my answer. These steps may be easier to follow.

Comment: soo.. It worked quiet well. I was able to deactivate SIP with the stick. Then I realised that my OS and Start Volume still contained data so I had to delete it and reinstall macOS. For some reason my WiFi wasn't working anymore (no symbol on the top right). So I had to install macOS with a ethernet cable. After the installation I trief to continue the tutorial: ( https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen/295805#295805 ) with
Part 2: improve thermal and power management
But the kext was not found so I assumed that with my reinstall it got lost

Comment: so i reseted the NVRAM and went through the process again. It worked and i did everything until part "Preventive measures for future use"
but why is my wireless still not working and not even appearing on my top right? and is it right that when I boot all these "white texts of black screen" are appearing before the apple logo? can/should i deactivate this?

But a big thanks already!!

Comment: @Robert Yarborough: Rather than post new questions a comments, you should actually post new questions. You can link back to this question if you wish.