# MacBook Pro late 2011 cannot boot using regular tactics

Tags: startup, hardware, recovery

I've tried every suggestion provided by Apple and a few i found here but am still unable to boot my laptop.

This occurred yesterday and i did manage to get in & do some work. However this morning (exactly the same as yesterday) as soon as i opened & started using Mail it crashed.

the difference today is that nothing gets me in now.

On the white screen i get the owl icon & pw field but once enetered the progress bar quits between 50-75% way through every time.

I tried the internet reset option but it also failed!

I'm on a pension & trying to start my new biz (design etc) to support myself so i do not have money to take it to a repair mob so am desperately seeking a solution here.

am not overly tech yet but am able to follow instructions as have been using Macs for 20 yrs but this has stumped me!

Any solutions??

**UPDATE!! check this out for full solution!**
[GPU problem - Boot Hangs on Grey Screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen/295805#295805)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a good chance your hard drive may be dying, in which case you could lose all your data if it is not backed up. Hopefully you already have a backup. If not, let me know and I can walk you through that.

**This assumes you have a full backup of your computer already:**

What happens when you hold **Command + R** while turning on your Macbook Pro with the power button? If you can get into the Recovery Partition this way, the first thing to try would be repairing permissions.

You do this by first clicking "Disk Utility" then selecting Macintosh HD. Click "First Aid" and then let it run. Once that's complete, restart your computer and see if that resolves the issue. If not, let me know and we can move on to the next troubleshooting step.

Comment: Command + R produces a white screen with apple icon & progress bar which fails about half way through & goes back to the white screen. Have checked files using Single User mode & see no probs there. Also was able (after several failed attempts) to gwt to the Apple Hardware Test which said all was fine. FOUND IN FORUMS, many people complaining that their earlier version MBPro crashed (like mine did which is rare), & they cannnot get back in due to Sierra OS. There is a bug in it (prob intentional). You either have to start over with an earlier OS or get a new Mac. Have you heard about this??

Comment: Great news about Apple Hardware Test passing! There is a good chance this is just a software bug (i've seen it many times, not necessarily an issue with Sierra).

Comment: You didn't specify that you have a working backup, but assuming you do, the next step is to wipe everything from your harddrive, re-install your operating system (Sierra), then transfer all your user data back. Create a bootable installer following this link: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201372  then boot (again holding option key on boot). Format Macintosh HD (DELETES ALL INFORMATION), then go back a window to install High Sierra. After High Sierra is reinstalled, migrate your time machine backup following: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204350