# How to know if Macbook Pro new Logic Board has new video chipset

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, video, gpu

I have a Late 2011 Macbook Pro which has been unusable for a couple months due to the famous GPU issue found on those machines. I went to a place where they repair those kind of things and they told me to buy a new Logic Board and they would install it. I had to make sure it had the new video chipset so the same wouldn't happen again. The guy told me to buy this one:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-MacBook-Pro-Unibody-15-A1286-i7-2-2GHz-Logic-Board-820-2915-A-B-2011/182498489271?hash=item2a7dc1f3b7:g:olYAAOSwhQhY0erb

The thing is I bought it and brought it to the guy and he now says the new Logic Board has the GPU issue and that it doesn't have the new chipset.

I want to know if it's possible to know if it has the new video chipset or not.

PS: I live outside the US so it'd be hard to return it.

Comment: The chips will have a model and rev number on them (I don't have the numbers, so not posting as an answer) and you can tell which is the older and the newer.  You should ask him (the guy) how he knows it's not correct because you need to file a claim with eBay.  After that, I would find someone different - a vendor who puts you in the middle of a dispute for a service you're paying for is one I would avoid.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen/295805#295805