# How to factory reset a MacBook Pro 2011 with a messed up GPU

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I have a 2011 MacBook Pro 15" which I want to clear all data on the hard drive but leave the OS.

The GPU works badly. Apple logo at startup is green, there is a lot of green… and after boot-up it ends on a white screen.

And thus I cannot get far with the normal methods (methods which use the display).

Is there another way I could do this reset?

Comment: How "badly" is it? Please describe the symptoms a bit more. What do you consider the "usual methods"?  And have you looked at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen/295805#295805)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are apparently quite some options left now.

1. Boot into SafeMode. Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> key on StartUp
   You will get unaccelerated display but the drivers for the GPU are not loaded and you should have still full access to the disk. Delete to your heart's content.
2. Take out the drive and mount it into an external case. Attach it to another Mac and do with it what you like to do.
3. Circumvent the discrete GPU by using this [procedure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen/295805#295805) This will give you an internal dsiplay with graphics acceleration from the Intel GPU. Remove all the stuff you like in that now resurrected MacBook Pro.
4. Create a USB-installer and boot from that thing. The installer should not use the discrete GPU and gives you the option to wipe/format the drive. That would be the true "factory reset".