# MacBookPro8,2 late 2011 GPU fix with EFI: how to do it on Catalina macOS 10.15 (dosdude1 patch)?

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu, efi, catalina

This guide https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/156133 is working fine on High Sierra. On Catalina installed with dosdude1 patcher (http://dosdude1.com/catalina/) I couldn't make it through, especially the thermal improvement.

I couldn't reload the `AMDRadeonX3000.kext` with `sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions-off/AMDRadeonX3000.kext`
. I've got this error:

`/System/Library/Extensions-off/AMDRadeonX3000.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) link error; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).`

I couldn't either create the `sudo nano /force-iGPU-boot.sh`, the permission being write only.

Does anyone have a solution how to run a broken GPU late 2011 on Catalina?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99697/discussion-between-langlangc-and-aroom).

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue trying to load the AMDRadeonX3000.kext after boot.

I was able to create the force-iGPU-boot script though, by mounting the Catalina system disk as R/W in terminal:

```
sudo mount -uw /
```

Comment: this worked for me too, but it seems that the script disappeared from /root ?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but perhaps more info for someone who can solve.  Having the same issue.  The system will boot with DosDude1's patch, but the AMD GPU is now being powered unfortunately.  Event with the kext available at boot, this is all that gets loaded:

```
com.apple.kext.AMDLegacySupport (1.6.6)
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller (1.6.6)
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport (1.6.6)
com.apple.kext.AMDLegacyFramebuffer (1.6.6)
```

Using `kextutil -v 6 /System/Library/Extensions-off/AMDRadeonX3000.kext` , it cites numerous malformed headers, ultimately failing to link and load.  Anxious to find a solution since booting is now a gamble.  This explains why I couldn't boot even with the kext deleted.