# MacBook Pro late 2011 AMD GPU disable

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu

I´ve done what's explained on "[GPU problem - Boot Hangs on Grey Screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen)" question.

In the option "about this Mac" only appear the Intel HD. The graphics card status app shows "i".

I searched for the amdradeon3000 kext on finder, and its in the folder I've created for backup on single user mode.

It seams to have worked, but it only boot correctly after a few power cycles to a black screen. Before it would show random graphics colours and glitches, or a grey or blue screen.

Using find command on user mode the amdradeonx3000.kext appears in 2 locations:
- .../extensions-off
and
- .../.pkinstallsandboxmanager-systemsoftware/nrsandletters.orphanedsandbox/root/system/library/extensions/amdradeonx3000.kext.

It is possible that this last one is causing the black screen at boot?

Should I move it to another folder?

Comment: Based on your description, you don’t have a discrete GPU.  If you don’t have the hardware, the kext isn’t loaded so moving/deleting it will have no effect.  Before you start moving kexts, a better course of action would be to run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Boot while holding  `D`.  Run the “Extended Tests” and post the results by [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/378013/edit) the current question.

Comment: Thank for your comment. Unfortunately the dGPU its on my mac. This was taken from a panic report occurred yesterday: "Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, PCIe". I will keep on studying this.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this last one is causing the black screen at boot? - I don't know yet. With verbose mode enable at some point it appears a message relating the reboot to a kernel panic.

Should I move it to another folder? - I've moved it. Don't know if it effects the boot sequence, but the behavior got regular.

Boot to a black screen, press power button to shutdown. Repeat 4 or 5 times. When the message about the panic shows, the boot process runs successfully.