# Late 2011 MacBook Pro 15" broken graphics - want to use external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, graphics, airplay

I recently wanted to add a monitor to my late 2011 MacBook Pro, but I have issue with main graphic card ([failed AMD GPU](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/force-2011-macbook-pro-8-2-with-failed-amd-gpu-to-always-use-intel-integrated-gpu-efi-variable-fix.2037591/)) that is connected to the HDMI port and the other graphic card doesn't seem to have any port I could plug into. Note I have verified the HDMI port is currently non-functional.

I'm thinking about alternatives:

- Apple TV or AirPlay (is this still supported by newer monitors?)
- USB/WiFi connection?

What would be the best option here? Except buying new MacBook Pro of course.

**Current state of my MBP:**

- OS: High Sierra 10.13.6
- it works fine until I have to reboot (below copy from the link to the forum what I do when MBP gets restarted)

**Procedure I use:**

```
1 - Boot Single User (press Command + S) at boot (If you have MacOS installed on your hard drive).

2 - If you have a blank HD, then use the USB stick/Pendrive with the MacOS installer (El Capitan, Sierra or HighSierra).

2.1 - Press Option key at boot, Position the mouse on the MacOS installer icon.

2.2 - Press Command + S and keep holding these two keys.

2.3 - Click the MacOS installer icon -> continue holding the Command + S keys until you finish the MacOS installer Single User boot .

Enter these commands (change gpu-power-prefs to Intel GPU and boot verbose):

nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00
nvram boot-args="-v"
reboot
```

Comment: You *HAVE* tried a cable in the HDMI port and you get no signal correct? The Mac should switch the two cards automatically and under light load it will use the Intel graphics hardware.

Comment: No; the HDMI port is hardwired to the dGPU: post#10 in the mentioned MacRumors thread.

Comment: Like @X_841 - it's not working, unfortunately. That's why I posted this

Comment: You need to clarify what your current state of the MacBook is in? Not booting, booting but with screen issue, booting fine, or whatever. Further, what macOS version is installed? Also, tell us exactly what steps you have done so far and don't just link a 109 pages thread...

Comment: @X_841 I just updated my question with current state of my MBP and procedure I use every time I need to reboot

Answer (score 1):

The linked forum thread has 109 pages; What is your current state of MacBook - what have you tried from that forum post?

If your MacBook is now working and using the integrated graphics card, you can try to buy a [USB to VGA](https://www.amazon.de/WAVLINK-DVI-Adapter-Windows-PCs-Displaylink-Aufl%C3%B6sung/dp/B08121WZT8/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=wavlink%20usb%202.0%20to%20VGA%20adapter&qid=1584023197&sr=8-5)/HDMI/... adapter.

Streaming to an Apple TV (which then connects to a TV/monitor) should work, even without the dedicated graphics card, but there are some limitations to it (e.g. may be slow, not ideal for videos/transitions,...). At least I could not find anything that implied it being a problem.

AirPlay is as far as I know only for music.

But you should probably read more about this problem [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/anyone-know-how-to-use-an-external-monitor-when-only-using-intel-integrated-gpu.2071248/).

Comment: I used method from the first post right under `Or try the simplest way - No needed ArchLinux - Only MacOS:` header. I also found [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/365416) - I'm thinking about hardware DeMoux fix to be honest. I want MBP to be fully working, even after reboot.

Comment: Well, what happened? Does it work? what is hardware *DeMoux*? You seem to have different questions: How to get my MBP running **and** how to connect my MBP to an external monitor. You link a thread here on AD, have you tried that, did it work?

Comment: I only want to connect MBP to external monitor. It is running so far. Haven't tried anything from that thread on AD here because I just found it today. Will need time to get through it cause it's very detailed.